# If $X$ has more than one element, then the norm $||f||=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$ doesn't come from a inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

> If $X$ has more than one element, then the norm $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$ doesn't come from a inner product in $B(X;\mathbb{R}) := \{f \mathpunct{:} X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is bounded$\}$

That is, there is no inner product $\langle-,-\rangle$ such that $\langle f,f\rangle = \|f\|^2$.

I thought of doing this in two ways: Set $\langle f,f \rangle = \|f\|^2$ and then getting a contradiction to the definition of inner product. Or showing a counterexample of the parallelogram law. In both cases I'm stuck on how to use that $X$ has more than one element. Any hint or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: A norm comes from an inner product if and only if it satisfies the parallelogram law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) which this norm does not.

Comment: Parallelogram law is the way to go. Say $a,b\in X$, $a\ne b$. _Use_ $a$ and $b$ to define two functions $f$ and $g$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ contains elements $a\neq b$, define $f(x) = \delta_{xa}$ and $g(x) = \delta_{xa} + \delta_{ba}$. Then
$$
2(\|f\|_\infty^2 + \|g\|_\infty^2) = 2 \neq 5 = \|f+g\|_\infty^2 + \|f-g\|_\infty^2
$$
so $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ doesn't satisfy the parallelogram law and hence isn't generated by an inner product.